# Where do I put my Buildr Integration tests?

Tags: java, integration-testing, buildr

I have a Java application that uses buildr.  My unit test are located in : src/test/java

The buildr doco talks about support for [integration tests](http://buildr.apache.org/testing.html#integration) but where do I put my integration tests? how to I separate them from unit tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up defining a subproject for the integration tests.  See below:

```
integration_layout = Layout.new
integration_layout[:source, :test, :java] = _('src/integration/java')
define "integrate", :layout => integration_layout do
    test.with TEST_CLASSPATH
    test.using :integration
    integration.setup { Rake::Task['my_project:jetty_start'].invoke }
    integration.teardown { Rake::Task['my_project:jetty_stop'].invoke }
end
```

I can then run the integration tests with the following command:

```
buildr integration
```

Answer (score 2):

Each buildr subproject can have either unit tests or integration tests. I use unit tests in each subproject that actually builds an artifact and then a separate subproject just for integration tests.